# Setting Permissions on MongoDB data/db directory

Tags: mongodb

I installed mongodb database using brew. When I run the mongod command in the terminal I get the following:

```
exception in initAndListen: 20 Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
```

I used my Mac GUI to give permissions as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Did you click on "Apply to enclosed items" under the gear icon at the bottom of that window?

Comment: @KevinAdistambha That was the issue and now it works. If you can post this as your answer then I can accept it.

Comment: Answered below, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make the permission changes permanent in MacOS, you would need to click on "Apply to enclosed items" under the gear icon at the bottom of the Information window.